# jsf tag not rendered in error page

Tags: java, jsf-2, web.xml, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have configured error page for HTTP 404 error in web.xml like this

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/Common/error.jspx</location>
</error-page>
```

Faces Servlet is configured as follows

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My error page (error.jspx) looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"
      xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Error Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body id="b1">

      <h4 style="color:red">An Error Occured. Please click Back button or Signout.</h4>
      <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back()"/>
      <tr:commandButton id="cb1" text="SIGN OUT" action="exit" actionListener="#{Login.LogOut}"/>    
  </body>
</html>
```

When I deploy application and run into 404 error, page displays error message with only Back button. I don't see SingOut button. I have checked url and it follows /faces/* pattern. Still to double check, I made a change and configured servlet mapping in web.xml as

```
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Still commandButton is not rendered. I understand that my error page don't have access to FacesContext or not going through Faces Servlet. I know this is a small issue, but couldn't figure out what can be done. I have also tried using .xhtml and .jsf as per googled suggestion. But no luck
I have tried different solutions to my problem and googled for solutions. But I couldn't get it resolved.

So can you please provide any suggestions...

Comment: Try accessing to your page manually by browsing `http://yourserver/yourWebAppName/faces/Common/error.jspx`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried accessing this page manually and page threw f:view tag missing erros. After I have added f:view to error page and it displayed SignOut button which means its working fine. But when I ran into error in application, this error page is broken and doesn't return anything, due to f:view tag. Any suggestions on how to approach this issue...